# Функция не возвращает значения из временной таблицы

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, temporary-table

Сделал функцию на plpgsql, где собираются данные из разных таблиц и записываются во временную, а после чтобы выдал только те колонки, которые описаны в переменной **p_select**, но выходит ошибка  "тип "**outquery**" не существует".
Что не так?

```
create or replace function run_report_01() returns setof outquery
as 
$function_text$
declare
  p_select text := ' id, name';
  p_where text := ' WHERE id > 1';
  outquery text;
begin 
CREATE TEMP TABLE outing (id integer, name text, rozn numeric(10,2)) on commit drop;
insert into outing (id, name, rozn) 
select cmp.id as id, cmp.name as name  , strinfo.str_retail as rozn from strinfo inner join cmp on strinfo.cmp_id=cmp.id where cmp.id='201';

outquery := 'select '|| p_select ||' from outing'|| p_where ;
  return query execute outquery;
end;
$function_text$
language plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После `returns setof` обязан быть указан тип результата. `plpgsql` и `sql` языкы строго типизированные. `returns setof outquery` воспринимается как возврат множества строк композитного типа `outquery`, объявленного пользователем.

Единственная возможность в разных случаях возвращать результат разных типов - это переложить обработку результата на вызывающую сторону и возвращать `setof record`. Повторюсь, описывать результат в этом случае будет обязанность вызывающего запроса, например:

```
select * from run_report_01() as result(id int, val text);
```

Если вызывающий запрос был описан неверно - будет ошибка.

Возвращать из одной хранимки разные типы данных в зависимости от каких-то условий - плохая идея в целом.

---

Также весьма рекомендую не злоупотреблять временными таблицами. Они безусловно дёргают диск и захламляют системный каталог. К тому же в подавляющем большинстве случаев могут быть легко заменены одним запросом, возможно `CTE`.